# Как создать копию View чтобы уменьшить код?

Tags: java, android

```
EditText editTextLeft = new EditText(this);
    editTextLeft.setHint("Название проекта");
    editTextLeft.setTextSize(12);
    editTextLeft.setSingleLine();
    editTextLeft.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT);
    editTextLeft.setHintTextColor(Color.GRAY);
    editTextLeft.setEnabled(false);

    EditText editTextRight = new EditText(this);
    editTextRight.setHint("Название обязанности");
    editTextRight.setTextSize(12);
    editTextRight.setSingleLine();
    editTextRight.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
    editTextRight.setHintTextColor(Color.GRAY);
    editTextRight.setEnabled(false);
```

Если присмотреться, то 2 объекта класса EditText почти одинаковые. Можно ли как-то создать копию 2 из 1, а после уже исправить значения.

То-бишь уменьшить код.

Сейчас это не критично, но в будущем, если мне придется писать для каждого View по 30 методов, то это будет ужасный код......

`EditText edittextRight=editextLeft` не работает

Comment: Попробуйте вместо `EditText editTextRight=editTextLeft` использовать `editTextLeft.clone()`.

Comment: Не работает в Android. Я пробовал. clone просто нету когда пишу точку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте метод

```
EditText createEditText() {
    EditText editText = new EditText(this);
    editTextLeft.setHint("Название проекта");
    editTextLeft.setTextSize(12);
    editTextLeft.setSingleLine();
    editTextLeft.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT);
    editTextLeft.setHintTextColor(Color.GRAY);
    editTextLeft.setEnabled(false);
    return editText;
}
```

И потом им создайте нужные вам элементы.

```
EditText editTextLeft = createEditText();
EditText editTextRight = createEditText();
```

Рекомендую почитать о порождающих шаблонах проектирования.

Comment: Ваш ответ не подходит. У вас получаются два одинаковых объекта, а надо разных (разные параметры)

Comment: @ЕвгенийТупиков, Нет не одинаковые. Ведь `new EditText` в методе используется. Значит разные.

Comment: @AndroLord ну в памяти да, это совершенно два разных объекта, но по структуре они одинаковые, я это и имел в виду. Просто надо было дополнить ответ, как у автора выше. Чем более развернут ответ, тем лучше!

Comment: Дак мне этого и достаточно. Пусть создаются все одинаково я ведь после могу приписать каждому другое text допустим и все. Я просто думал что через равно проканает. Оказалось нет. А жаль...

Answer (score 3):

Николай Конорев ответил правильно.
Если вам нужно изменить какой-то из параметров, измените его после вызова метода создания `EditText`. Если этот параметр у всех разный, его стоит передавать параметром в метод `createEditText()`.

В вашем случае можно передать меняющиеся параметры так:

```
EditText createEditText(String hint, int imeOptions) {
        EditText editText = new EditText(this);
        editText.setHint(hint);
        editText.setTextSize(12);
        editText.setSingleLine();
        editText.setImeOptions(imeOptions);
        editText.setHintTextColor(Color.GRAY);
        editText.setEnabled(false);
        return editText;
}
```

Затем использовать этот метод таким образом:

```
EditText editTextLeft = createEditText("Название проекта", EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT);
EditText editTextRight = createEditText("Название обязанности", EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
```

После вызова этого метода, никто не мешает вам кастомизировать объект и дальше, например вы можете изменить параметры

```
editTextRight.setTextSize(17);
```

Или же установить новые

```
editTextRight.setText("");
```

Comment: Можно еще вспомнить паттерн Builder